# Папка ProgramData стала видимой

Tags: windows, windows-10

Кто знает, почему папка `ProgramData` стала видимой, если она должна быть скрытой?

[image: Видимая папка ProgramData]

Влияет ли это на что-нибудь, если да, то как можно её скрыть (применение атрибута `Скрытый` к папке через свойства ни к чему не привело)?

Comment: *Влияет ли это на что-нибудь* Вряд ли. *почему папка ProgramData стала видимой, если она должна быть скрытой? ... как можно её скрыть (применение атрибута Скрытый к папке через свойства ни к чему не привело)?* Убедитесь, что владельцем папки является встроенная учётная запись `СИСТЕМА`.

Comment: Владельцем папки является `СИСТЕМА` с полным дотупом.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не могу комментировать Ваш вопрос, не достаточно репы :(
Подскажите, что у Вас тут включено? Предполагаю, что включен просмотр скрытых файлов и папок, так как в директории у Вас отображается `скрытая` папка `$WinREAgent`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скриншоте в вопросе видно, что папка не является скрытой, поэтому данная настройка ни на что не повлияет

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, но я не уверен, что пользователь оставил атрибут `Скрытый` к данной папке, и поэтому для начала необходимо выключить отображение всех скрытых, а затем искать причину отображения.

Comment: @AlexRebell, у меня включено отображение всех скрытых папок, но даже если его выключить ситуация не меняется.